# Why my prefix doesn't work? - discord.js V12.2.0

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here are my two codes, they are in separate folders, what I try is that the message in embed can be used with my prefix, but when I use this command it does not matter the letters, numbers or symbols that I put behind it because the command is executed the same regardless of the prefix.

```
{
  "token": "(my token)",
  "prefix": "-"

}
```

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require ("discord.js");
const client = new Client();
const MessageAttachment = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

let prefix = config.prefix;

/////////////////BOT///////////////////

function doKissAction() {
    var rand = [
        'https://media2.giphy.com/media/G3va31oEEnIkM/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.tenor.com/images/fbb2b4d5c673ffcf8ec35e4652084c2a/tenor.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/ZRSGWtBJG4Tza/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/oHZPerDaubltu/giphy.gif',
        'https://acegif.com/wp-content/uploads/anime-kiss-m.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/bm2O3nXTcKJeU/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/nyGFcsP0kAobm/giphy.gif',
        'https://media0.giphy.com/media/KH1CTZtw1iP3W/source.gif'
    ];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
}

client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'kiss':
if(!args[1] ) {
    message.channel.send('¡Necesitas a alguien a quien besar!');
} else {
              const personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();
          const acceptedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(':sparkles: :heart: ¡Que romantico! :heart: :sparkles: ')
          .setImage(doKissAction())
          .setColor(0xF086FF)
          .setDescription('`' + message.author.username + '`' + ' ha besado a ' + '`' + personTagged.displayName + '`')
          message.channel.send(acceptedEmbed);
        //    personTagged.send();
}

    break;

   }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't checking if it starts with the prefix, you are just removing the prefix

```js
let args = message.content.split(" ");
let commandName = args[0];

if(!commandName.startsWith(prefix)) return;
commandName = commandName.slice(prefix.length);

switch(commandName) {
  case 'kick': {
    //..code
  }
}
```